# Segmentation Fault when i use GetInternalField() FROM V8 library

Tags: c++, v8

i use the newer version of the v8 library. When i run demo from [this page(process.cc)](https://v8.dev/docs/embed),

my program crash when GetInternalField is called in UnwrapMap function. Does anyone have a similar problem, or does they know how to solve it?
Here example:

```
map<string, string>* JsHttpRequestProcessor::UnwrapMap(Local<Object> obj) {
  Local<External> field = Local<External>::Cast(obj->GetInternalField(0)); // here segmentation fault
  void* ptr = field->Value();
  return static_cast<map<string, string>*>(ptr);
}
```

EDIT:

I solved my problem. I had to insert macro V8_COMPRESS_POINTERS = 1. Thank you

Comment: Segmentation fault is a pretty straight forward error; you accessed memory outside your allocated address space.

Comment: First see if obj is not nullptr, second on a separate line just try calling obj->getInternalField(0) and see what it returns. If no crash, then most likely the ::cast is going wrong

Comment: Thank you for reply. Obj is not nullptr. Crash only if is called  obj->GetInternalField(0). Calling other method is ok (for example obj->GetIdentityHash() is ok)

Comment: obj might not be setup properly. Maybe try instantiating a default object of Local<Object> obj and call GetInternalField(0)

Answer (score 0):

The provided sample works fine here; did you modify it in any way? How exactly are you running it?

You can only call `obj->GetInternalField(0)` if you know that `obj` is an object with internal fields. You can use `obj->InternalFieldCount()` to check. Objects only have internal fields if you, the embedder, gave them any. If you are trying to convert a regular JavaScript object to a C++ map, you'll have to iterate over its properties, not its internal fields.

Comment: Thanky you for comment. When i call obj->InternalFieldCount(), returned value is 1. From sample...I only changed 'string file' To 'string file = "/home/aloha/test"' where test is file with this content: 'options.test;' When file is empty, its work, because it does not call UnwrapMap, where is GetInternalField(0).

Comment: When i call result->SetInternalField(0, map_ptr); and then immediately result->GetInternalField(0); result is same....segmentation fault.